# Another crossword of mine

Tags: crosswords

[image]

##### Across

**1** Pa alternative
**4** A friend of the hiders *(2 words)*
**13** Some SE housekeeping
**16** Jackie Harris, for one
**17** An opera piece
**18** Mrs. Perón
**19** "The best man in the government"
**20** Support garment
**21** Parts of curves
**22** Stop talking! *(2 words)*
**23** Flanders and Swann subject
**24** Den
**26** Bobbies, for example
**29** Choose
**31** Not us
**33** CIA predecessor
**35** Crib death: *abbr.*
**37** Foe
**39** Decline
**41** Older brother to a fresh., perhaps
**43** 1990s Speaker of the House
**45** Earth: *comb. form*
**46** Duke & MIT, e.g.
**48** A former island in East Anglia
**49** A hairdo
**50** Hexagonal
**51** Paddle
**52** A Swedish manufacturer
**54** Yens
**55** A nitrogen ion
**57** Sixteen before 1 Across
**59** U.S. warning mechanism
**61** A Greencloak, in children's literature
**63** Tet follower
**64** Snoozes
**65** Failure
**66** Isaac's son
**67** *Dunciad* writer
**68** Dance
**69** One of the Carpenters
**71** Nirvana tune *(2 words)*
**73** Golly
**75** Assuage
**77** Olé, to Eleni
**78** Ear part
**80** Puts down
**82** Triglav, for one
**84** Dull
**87** A transportation means
**89** Mayday
**90** Flump
**91** Cobra ___
**92** A Hadid
**93** Ireland
**94** Boston or Chicago team
**95** Binding
**96** John, in Gaelic
**97** Knuth's system

##### Down

**1** Paul, in Spanish
**2** One of 114 chapters
**3** One ___ million
**4** There are two on Panama's flag
**5** Drug enforcer
**6** A sort of monster
**7** Tufts
**8** A hunk
**9** Discoverer of an area formula
**10** Hoagy Carmichael standard
**11** Tense
**12** With nothing
**13** Relax
**14** A prong
**15** A small amount
**25** Where Bill Cosby first led *(2 words)*
**27** German border river
**28** Game with striped squiggles
**30** Exfoliants
**32** Henry, in French
**34** Cup brand
**36** Facts
**38** One of the Howards
**40** A sorta nonfiction
**41** The number of hiders
**42** The rich
**44** Planet
**45** Wadis
**46** Open, in a way
**47** Rutabaga
**50** Eon
**53** Sami
**54** Appropriate
**55** Solomon's lily, for example
**56** 36 Down
**58** The way
**60** George Gordon's daughter
**62** Pearl Harbor site
**63** Indian practice
**66** Last word of many a bedtime story
**68** A lot
**69** Neat
**70** Dine where you are *(2 words)*
**71** Zadoc & Og's boss: *informal*
**72** Star of an eponymous show
**74** Lower East Side street
**76** Other: *comb. form*
**77** Like some barrels
**79** Pope John XVII's year
**81** Back then
**83** Skin disease
**85** Mai ___
**86** One of a dozen, often
**88** Since
**89** Be parked

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finished grid

> [image: Filled crossword grid]

Across

> 1 Pa alternative **PSI** (unit of pressure)
>  4 A friend of the hiders **SNOW WHITE** (see below)
>  13 Some SE housekeeping **VTC**?
>  16 Jackie Harris, for one **AUNT**
>  17 An opera piece **ARIA**
>  18 Mrs. Perón **EVA**
>  19 "The best man in the government" **MEIR**, (Golda)
>  20 Support garment **BRA**
>  21 Parts of curves **ARCS**
>  22 Stop talking! **DRY UP!**
>  23 Flanders and Swann subject **[GNU](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YqgPyqyh4X4)**
>  24 Den **LAIR**
>  26 Bobbies, for example **COPS**
>  29 Choose **OPT**
>  31 Not us **THEM**
>  33 CIA predecessor **OSS** (Office of Strategic Services)
>  35 Crib death **SIDS** (sudden infant death syndrome)
>  37 Foe **ENEMY**
>  39 Decline **EBB**
>  41 Older brother to a fresh., perhaps **SOPH.**
>  43 1990s Speaker of the House **NEWT** (Gingrich)
>  45 Earth **GEO-**
>  46 Duke & MIT, e.g. **UNIS**
>  48 A former island in East Anglia **ELY**
>  49 A hairdo **AFRO**
>  50 Hexagonal **[ALLEN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_key)**
>  51 Paddle **ROW**
>  52 A Swedish manufacturer **VOLVO**
>  54 Yens **URGES**
>  55 A nitrogen ion **AZIDE**
>  57 Sixteen before (PSI) **ETA** (Greek letter)
>  59 U.S. warning mechanism **EAS** (Emergency Alert System)
>  61 A Greencloak, in children's literature **[LENORI](https://spiritanimals.fandom.com/wiki/Lenori)**
>  63 Tet follower **YOD** (Hebrew letter)
>  64 Snoozes **NAPS**
>  65 Failure **DUD**
>  66 Isaac's son **ESAU**
>  67 *Dunciad* writer **POPE**, (Alexander)
>  68 Dance **HOP**
>  69 One of the Carpenters **[KAREN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karen_Carpenter)**
>  71 Nirvana tune **OH ME**
>  73 Golly **GEE**
>  75 Assuage **EASE**
>  77 Olé, to Eleni **OPA** (Greek expression)
>  78 Ear part **DRUM**
>  80 Puts down **LAYS**
>  82 Triglav, for one **ALP**
>  84 Dull **MATTE**
>  87 A transportation means **RAIL**
>  89 Mayday **SOS**
>  90 Flump **PLOP**
>  91 Cobra ___ **[KAI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cobra_Kai)**
>  92 A Hadid **[GIGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigi_Hadid)**
>  93 Ireland **ÉIRE**
>  94 Boston or Chicago team **SOX** (Red Sox, White Sox)
>  95 Binding **TYING**
>  96 John, in Gaelic **EOIN**
>  97 Knuth's system **[TEX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeX)**

Down

> 1 Paul, in Spanish **PABLO**
>  2 One of 114 chapters **SURA** (chapter of the Qur'an)
>  3 One ___ million **IN A**
>  4 There are two on Panama's flag **STARS**
>  5 Drug enforcer **NARC**
>  6 A sort of monster **ORC**
>  7 Tufts **WISPS**
>  8 A hunk **WAD**
>  9 Discoverer of an area formula **[HERON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula)**
>  10 Hoagy Carmichael standard **[IVY](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oxiAf-RIb24)**
>  11 Tense **TAUT**
>  12 With nothing **EMPTY**
>  13 Relax **VEG**
>  14 A prong **TINE**
>  15 A small amount **CRUMB**
>  25 Where Bill Cosby first led **[I SPY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Spy_(1965_TV_series))**
>  27 German border river **ODER**
>  28 Game with striped squiggles **[SET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(card_game))**
>  30 Exfoliants **PEELS**
>  32 Henry, in French **HENRI**
>  34 Cup brand **SOLO**
>  36 Facts **INFO**
>  38 One of the Howards **[MOE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moe_Howard)**
>  40 A sorta nonfiction **BIO**
>  41 The number of hiders **SEVEN** (see below)
>  42 The rich **HAVES** (vs. "have-nots")
>  44 Planet **WORLD**
>  45 Wadis **GLENS**
>  46 Open, in a way **UNZIP**
>  47 Rutabaga **SWEDE**
>  50 Eon **AGE**
>  53 Sami **LAPPS**
>  54 Appropriate **USURP**
>  55 Solomon's lily, for example **ARUM** (genus of plants)
>  56 (INFO) **DOPE**
>  58 The way **TAO**
>  60 George Gordon's daughter **ADA** (Lovelace)
>  62 Pearl Harbor site **OAHU**
>  63 Indian practice **YOGA**
>  66 Last word of many a bedtime story **END**
>  68 A lot **HEAPS**
>  69 Neat **KEMPT**
>  70 Dine where you are **EAT IN**
>  71 Zadoc & Og's boss: **ORRIE**?
>  72 Star of an eponymous show **ELLEN** (DeGeneres)
>  74 Lower East Side street **ESSEX**
>  76 Other **ALLO-**
>  77 Like some barrels **OAKY**
>  79 Pope John XVII's year **MIII** (1003)
>  81 Back then **YORE**
>  83 Skin disease **POX**
>  85 Mai ___ **TAI**
>  86 One of a dozen, often **EGG**
>  88 Since **AGO**
>  89 Be parked **SIT**

What else is going on?

> Notice how two answers mention "hiders". Their friend is SNOW WHITE, and there are SEVEN of them. Putting on the thinking cap... Yep, it turns out we have certain [short-statured individuals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_Dwarfs#Disney_Dwarfs) hiding in the grid!
>
>  [image: Filled crossword grid with seven words highlighted]

The title

> The dwarfs in Snow White are miners, so it's a "crossword of *mine*"!